# How to calculate rolling average of past 1 month in R

Tags: r, window, time-series

Most packages and posts I found apply mean to a fixed size window or the aggregate month/week data. Is it possible to calculate rolling k month average?

For example, for **1 month rolling window**, assuming the data is:

```
Date          Value
2012-05-28    101
2012-05-25     99
2012-05-24    102
....
2012-04-30     78
2012-04-27     82
2012-04-26     77
2012-04-25     75
2012-04-24     76
```

The first three rolling 1 month windows should be:

```
1. 2012-05-28 to 2012-04-30
2. 2012-05-25 to 2012-04-26
3. 2012-05-24 to 2012-04-25
```

Please note that this is NOT the fixed width rolling window. The window actually changes on the daily basis.

Comment: Take a look at `rollmean` from the `zoo` package.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/743812/602276

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. but those only apply to FIXED rolling windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a set containing count of data in rolling set of buckets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741180/how-to-make-a-set-containing-count-of-data-in-rolling-set-of-buckets)

Comment: how are you defining a month?  look back 30 days? look back to the previous day of the month?  I'm not sure I understand how the window width is changing...

Comment: Related: [Rolling list over unequal times in xts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722512/rolling-list-over-unequal-times-in-xts), [Rolling window over irregular time series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556450/rolling-window-over-irregular-time-series)

Comment: @Andrie this is close, but the endpoints looks weird though. it does not cut off the exact month-ends.

Comment: @Justin one month relative to date: [yyyy-mm-dd] is [yyyy-(mm-1)-dd + 1], where (+1) is used to exclude the end points.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich i think this is possible, but looping into every element of the series would definitely be my last resort

Comment: So one month ago from `2012-05-30` is `2012-04-31`?  Awesome!

Comment: @JackManey should be 2012-05-01... date+1 can automatically do the month/year increment

Comment: If `dd` is simply an integer, then there is nothing that inherently prevents `dd>31`.

Comment: @JackManey sorry, maybe i didn't clarify enough. what i mean by +1 to a date is actually as.Date('yyyy-mm-dd') + 1. anyway, i'm just trying to show the idea, not the exact expression or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to calculate monthly averages based on daily price data.

```
#function for extracting month is in the lubridate package
install.packages(c("plyr", "lubridate"))
require(plyr); require(lubridate)

#read the daily data
daily = read.csv("daily_lumber_prices.csv")
price = daily$Open
date = daily$Date

#convert date to a usable format
date = strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y")
mon = month(date)
T = length(price)

#need to know when months change
change_month = rep(0,T)

for(t in 2:T){
  if(mon[t] != mon[t-1]){
    change_month[t-1] = 1
  }
}

month_avg = rep(0,T)
total = 0
days = 0

for(t in 1:T){
  if(change_month[t] == 0){
    #cumulative sums for each variable
    total = total + price[t] 
    days = days + 1
  }

  else{
    #need to include the current month in the calculation
    month_avg[t] = (total + price[t]) / (days + 1)
    #reset the variables
    total = 0
    days = 0
  }
}
```

So, the variable month_avg is storing the monthly averages.

Is it something like this? This code accounts for the variable lengths of months. There's certainly a more efficient way to do it, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is `df` this works for me:

```
df$past_avg = sapply(df$Date, function(i){
    i = as.POSIXct(i)
    mean(subset(df, Date > (i - months(1)) & Date < i)$Value)
})
```

Uses just base R. You can adjust to however many months in the past you want by changing the value in `months()`.

Answer (score 0):

[runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) package fully supports rolling windows operations on irregulary spaced time series. To calculate **1-month** moving average on `x` object one have to specify `idx = date` (to make a runner time dependent) and `k = "1 months"` or `k = 30` (days) depending what is more important to user. User can [apply any R function](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/apply_any_r_function.html) - in this case we execute `mean`.

```r
# example data
x <- cumsum(rnorm(20))
date <- Sys.Date() + cumsum(sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)) # unequaly spaced time series

# calculate rolling average
runner::runner(
  x = x, 
  k = "1 months", 
  idx = date, 
  f = mean
)
```